# How to play flash with JCEF

Tags: java, flash, chromium-embedded

I have Swing embedded browser application which is implemented using JCEF, it does not play flash, how to make it support flash? My OS is Windows 10, jdk1.8 and the JCEF is pulled using maven as following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bitbucket.johness</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-cef</artifactId>
    <version>49.87.win64.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The following is my code

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
    settings.cache_path="d:/cefCache";
    String[] args={
        //  "--ppapi-flash-path=\"C:\\Users\\wei\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\PepperFlash\\26.0.0.151\\pepflashplayer.dll\"",
        //  "--ppapi-flash-version=26.0.0.151",
            "--enable-system-flash=true",
            "--plugin-policy=allow"
            };
    String startURL="http://saizenmedia.com/fubon/";
//  String startURL="http://192.168.86.27:8086/?name=keno";
    CefApp cefApp = CefApp.getInstance(args,settings);
    CefClient client = cefApp.createClient();
    CefBrowser browser = client.createBrowser(startURL, false, false);
    Component browerUI = browser.getUIComponent();
    JTextField address = new JTextField(startURL, 100);
    address.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            browser.loadURL(address.getText());
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(address, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    getContentPane().add(browerUI, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    setSize(800,600);
    setVisible(true);
```

[image: Here is what I see when run the application.]

Edits:

I do have "Opera and Chromium PPAPI" version flash installed
I have downloaded the builds from here http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html
The flash is playing fine when I use cefclient.exe with "--enable-system-flash"

But Java is my language of choice for my application, hence JCEF. It seems the flag "--enable-system-flash" is lost between JCEF and CEF. 
Any suggestions please?

Edits:

The problem was the following code which was not posted. It works fine once I replaced the null with args

```
    CefApp.addAppHandler(new CefAppHandlerAdapter(null) {
        @Override
        public void stateHasChanged(org.cef.CefApp.CefAppState state) {
            if (state == CefAppState.TERMINATED){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you see in your app? Any error messages? If you right-click where Flash content is position / area, what happens (does right-click menu say anything about Flash version)?

Comment: @VC.One I have added a screenshot